# Street adress cleaning in R

Tags: r, regex, expression

I want to clean the street address which is given as follows , for example:

121/122/123 15th clyde road

121-122 10th broward lane

I am using regular expression in R somewhat like:

```
sub((\\s*[/ ]\\d+\\s*){1, }
```

Although , it is almost giving me the desired output, but the term "10th" and "15th" is getting converted to "th" which shoud not be the case.

The correct output should be:

(i)   121 15th clyde road

(ii)  121 10th broward lane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data:

```
str <- c("121/122/123 15th clyde road", "121-122 10th broward lane", 
     "357 / 122 /123 17th peter road", "121- 122- 123 -124 10th aremand road")
```

Solution:

```
gsub("(/(\\s)?\\d+{1,}|-(\\s)?\\d+){1,}", "", str)
[1] "121 15th clyde road"    "121 10th broward lane"  "357   17th peter road"  "121  10th aremand road"
```

Comment: Ok...but what if there are multiple numbers in between and there are some irregular spaces or any other seperator.For example,  "121- 122-  123  -124 10th aremand road".

Comment: See update. It'd be helpful if you specified the pattern in more detail.

Comment: See another update to account for irregular spacing.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Do feel free to accept the answer by clicking the green tick in the left upper corner of the answer--that's the way to express gratitude on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, you just need to remove a series of character starting with `/` or `-` and followed by a number. You can easily do that using the following regex `[-/]\\d+`.

With `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

v <- c("121/122/123 15th clyde road", "121-122 10th broward lane")
str_remove_all(v, "[-/]\\d+")
# [1] "121 15th clyde road"   "121 10th broward lane"
```

Or using `gsub` function:

```
v <- c("121/122/123 15th clyde road", "121-122 10th broward lane")
gsub("[-/]\\d+", "", v)
# [1] "121 15th clyde road"   "121 10th broward lane"
```